# Bootsrap, Required, Fontawesome, and ASP.NET webforms

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-4, webforms, font-awesome

I'm trying to do something which I think should be doable, but I'm having problems with.  Here are my requirements:

- I need to check that four values on a webform form are entered.
- I need to allow a user to submit the data on a button click.
- The button has some text and has some fontawesome icons in it.
- When the data is submitted, I need to turn off the button so that the user does not inadvertently click it again and submit the exact same data the second time.
- Get the required popups from bootstrap on an insert/update of data, assuming some data has not been entered.

I am only able to get pieces of this working.  Here is what I have tried:

- An asp:LinkButton.  I can get everything but the bootstrap required popups.  I found that this seems to be caused because bootstrap required looks for a button of type "submit".
- An asp:Button.  I can get everything but the fontawesome icons.  I found that I can actually insert this on a jquery document ready method, but I get all kinds of asp .net security violations when I try this.  I simply can't open this up.
- A button tag with a runat="server" on it.  I've tied this in with the asp.net button click event like below.  Unfortunately, when I click the button, if there is a client side onclick event handler, the server side click event never gets called.  I am able to style the button like a link.  This is the option that seems to get me the closest.  Unfortunately, I seem to be able to get the client side onclick event or the server side onserverclick event, but not both. I'm open to any and all suggestions here.

  ```
   <button type="submit" ID="btnSubmission" runat="server" 
   onserverclick="lbCaseUpdate_Click" 
   class="buttonAsLink nav-link pl-0" ><i class="fa fa-pen fa-fw"></i> Update</button>
  ```

What I need is a button/link that activates the "required" display in bootstrap, contains the fontawesome icons, runs some client side javascript to somehow communicate an update is occurring, turns off the input button, and then performs the server side operation.  I don't see how to get it.  I'm open to any and all suggestions.

TIA

Comment: after a lot of googling and trying some things, I figured out that the onclick was overriding the onserverclick when I looked at the html generated.  I looked at the code, and finally figured out out to do it.  If someone finds this usefully, here goes.  I had to use my client side javascript.  Inside of it, I created an __dopostback passing the id of the button and a parameter.  I then had to in my pageload event, look for the parameter, and if I found it, I called my update method.  I feel dirty.